# jQuery Form Fields Calculations showing + or - Result

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm making a form in which there is an expectant total and where there is an actual total. The last field should display the differences in the field values. So what the code should do is show a negative or positive number after comparing the data in the field and the result should also change if these base numbers are changed. Here's what I have so far:

I have more code above this and the below piece of code is working fine, it's just not showing if the number is negative or positive.

```
var difference = ztotal - total;
```

Here is where I'm having an issue, the first part of the code is working okay and showing a negative number, but the second part is adding a "+-". I need to remove the plus or minus if the ztotal or total amount changes to reflect the correct result.

```
  if(ztotal > total){
    $('#difference').val(parseFloat(difference).toFixed(2) * -1);
  }
  else {
    $('#difference').val('+' + parseFloat(difference).toFixed(2));
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. The `parseFloat` function converts variables of type `String` to whatever you need, in this case, a float. Just scrap the use of that function
2. Why check if one is greater than the other, and not just simply output the number. For instance:

   ```
   var difference = total - ztotal;
   $("#difference").val((difference > 0 ? "+" : "") + difference.toFixed(2));
   ```

That example uses the shorthand if-else structure. That is the part that looks like this:

```
    difference > 0 ? "+" : ""
```

All that it means is if the variable `difference` is greater than 0, write a "+", otherwise, write a "" (blank string). It just saves space!

Comment: Ahha! You made me realise I made another mistake:

`var difference = ztotal - total;`

should be:

`var difference = total - ztotal;`

The negative number now shows a '-', the only thing left to do is add a '+' when it's a positive number. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Can anyone make a suggestion on how to add a '+' when it's a positive number and then remove it if the totals change and make it negative?

Comment: If the number is greater than 0, add the plus sign. Otherwise, don't. :)

Comment: Thanks Connor but can you show me with code what you would do? I can add the '+' if the number is >  0 but how to remove again if the total changes to 0 or a minus number?

Comment: I'll revise my answer to add that!